# How to combine two arrays using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have two array which is like to be

```
var array1=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5,','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10,','a11','a12'----];
var array2=['b1','b2','b3','b4',----];
var result= [];
```

I want to show result array as

```
result= ['a1','a2','b1','a3','a4,','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9,','a10','a11','b2','a12']
```

second array 'array2' values placed in the position of 3,12,19,28,35...(series like 3,3+9,12+7,19+9,28+7 etc)
If 'array1' has less value than 'array2' then values should place continuously in 'result[]' for eg:

```
array1=['a1','a2','a3'];
array2=['b1','b2','b3'];
```

then

```
result=['a1','a2','b1','a3','b2','b3'];
```

How to implement this by using jquery?

Comment: what is the value after 35?

Comment: the serious going continuously 44,73--(35+9,44+7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast way to manage this. But it could be optimized.

```js
var array1=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5,','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10,','a11','a12'];
var array2=['b1','b2','b3','b4'];
document.body.innerHTML += "arr1:" + array1 + "<br/>";
    document.body.innerHTML += "arr2:" + array2 + "<br/>";
var result= [];

var index=0;
var lastInsertedBindex=0;
var step1 = 9;
var step2 = 7;
var lastUsedStep = step2;
var nextStepIndex = 3;
elements = true;
var indexFromA = 0;
var indexFromB = 0;
var elementsExists = true;
do{
  if( index != nextStepIndex ){
    if( undefined != array1[indexFromA] ){
      result.push( array1[indexFromA]);
      indexFromA++;
    } else if( undefined != array2[indexFromB]){
      result.push( array2[indexFromB]);
      indexFromB++;
    } else 
      elementsExists = false;
    
    index++;
    continue;
  }else{
    if( undefined != array2[indexFromB] ){
      result.push(array2[indexFromB]);
      indexFromB++;
      lastUsedStep = lastUsedStep == step1 ? step2 : step1;
      nextStepIndex = nextStepIndex + lastUsedStep; 
    } else if( undefined != array1[indexFromA]) {
      result.push(array1[indexFromA]);
      indexFromA++;
      
    } else 
       elementsExists = false;
        
    index++;
  }
  
  
}while(elementsExists);
document.body.innerHTML += "res:" + result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
// Create arrays
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
for(i=1;i<100;i++){
  array1[array1.length] = "a"+i;
}
for(i=2;i<50;i++){
  array2[array2.length] = "b"+i;
}

// The function
function coupleArrays(array1, array2){
  var newArray = [];
  var jump = 9; // first jump
  var pos = 3; // Starting point

  while(array1.length > 0){
    var i = newArray.length;

    if(i == pos-1 && array2.length != 0){
      // remove first from array2 and add to newArray
      newArray[i] = array2.shift(); 

      pos += jump; // add the jump to get new position

      // set jump to 9 or 7
      if(jump == 9) jump = 7;
      else jump = 9;

    }else{
      // remove first from array1 and add to newArray
      newArray[i] = array1.shift();
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
var coupled = coupleArrays(array1, array2);

// Just to show output
for(i=0;i<coupled.length;i++){
  var nr = i;
  if( nr < 10 ) nr = "0"+nr;
  if( nr < 100 ) nr = "0"+nr;
  document.write( nr + ": " + coupled[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to loop round `array2`, slice the first x items to result (depending on which iteration it could be 3, 7, or 9) and append the current index from `array2`.  Then once you've run out of elements in `array1` continue to add elements from `array2`.

```js
var array1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10', 'a11', 'a12'];
var array2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'];
var result = [];

// Values to increase by
var add = [7, 9];

var originalArray1Length = array1.length;

if (array2.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array1.length != 0) {
      // If we're on the first loop we increase by 3 otherwise we get the modulus of the loop 
      // iteration and use it to reference the "add" array
      result = result.concat(array1.splice(0, i == 0 ? 2 : add[i % 2]));
    }
    result[result.length] = array2[i];
  }
} else
  result = array1;

document.getElementById('result').innerText = result.join(',');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **recursive** function to solve this:

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

// Preparing data
for (var i = 0, len = 100; i < len; ++i) {
  array1[i] = 'a' + (i + 1);
  array2[i] = 'b' + (i + 1);
}

var index = 3;
function insert (arr1, arr2, i) {
  // Insert element to array
  array1.splice(index - 1, 0, array2[i]);
  index = ((index % 2) == 1) ? index + 9 : index + 7;
  if ( index < arr2.length - 1) { insert(arr1, arr2, i + 1) }
  return;
}

insert(array1, array2, 0);
array1.forEach( function (item) {
  let output = (item.indexOf('b') !== -1) ? '<b>' + item + ' </b>' 
              : item + ' ';
  $('#result').append(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```